# How to spend any ERC20 token with web3 (or how to find ABI from a contract address)?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I use web3 and I would like to know when somebody sent me any kind of ERC20 token. With web3, I can get the "to" and the "input" fields. With the "to", I get the contract address. With the "input", I get the recipient and the number of tokens transferred. Then, I want to spend those tokens. For that I need to connect to the contract so I need the ABI.

My questions: where can I find the ABI since I don't have the contract source ? It is possible to find the contract source ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Ethereum address, you can go here: http://etherscan.io to get a list of all transactions and, if the person/people who wrote the smart contract posted such, you can get both the source code and the ABI.

The only trouble that I've had with this approach, and it's only a philosophical one, is that this is centralized. A better approach would be a fully decentralized source of this same information. I believe the people working in the ENS (http://ens.domains/) are working on this functionality, but I don't think it's yet available (or if it is, it's not widely implemented).

Comment: So it is not possible to automatize this process with web3 ?

Comment: I don't think so because the chain is public. Everyone can see everything.